# Javascript Overlay functionality as like flipkart zoom of particular area of the product whenever movement happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to create a function to like elevate the specific  area wherever the rectangular box move. Example : Flipkart product zoom functionality i.e.when the rectangular box moves to specific area of the product it gets zoomed and that particular part only gets zoomed,since that's image im facing little bit different issue wherein i have to zoom the specific area of the div.

Folks give some suggestions...

Comment: Sorry, but over SO, we do not recommend. You will have to search manually and try few things on your own. Then, if you stuck, we can help you. But until then, we cannot help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many plugin you can use to do the functionality.
Check below sites.

http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-zoom-effect/

I have used this - http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/

Upvote if it helped.

Comment: @VinodG Thank you so much :) i was able to apply the functionality with image but my problem is i have to do it with a particular div...to be precise i have a page which is divided into two parts Left(L) and Right(R),in general L has event generators as if i click on some event the activities for that event will be displayed in R...in order to give good UX i created div in corner of R which has small boundaries and acts as a clone of R as whatever changes happens in R will dynamically be reflected in that clone div. now i added a small rectangle in that clone div as if i drag it same area

Comment: should be displayed in the R div.

Comment: we should not recommend. Recommendations are based on opinions.